# When can I be confident that I've fixed an intermittent problem?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have a network server which has been experiencing problems for the last few days, which is monitored by an external program (Pingdom, to be specific).  I've just made a change to the network server to try and alleviate the problem, and I'd like to have some idea how long I have to wait, without seeing any further instances of the problem, before I can declare "mission accomplished".

What the monitoring service gives me is a log of when it detected the service was up and down.  It looks something like this:

[image: example of dataset]

Is the solution as simple as, say, treating each minute as a sample, using the samples over the time period things were *definitely* broken (I know when I made the change that started the problem, and when I applied the "treatment") as the "control" group, and then when I have an unbroken stream of "all is well" results after the treatment of some length, I can say "yep, that worked!" to some degree of confidence?  Or is that a completely invalid way to approach the problem?

For the record, I'm embarrassingly inept at applied statistics, so this may be a "stats 101" type question, but I can't seem to map the sorts of techniques I can find on the Internet (and the "Statistics in a Nutshell" book I bought to try and remedy my ineptitude) to this particular problem.  So once I get pointed in a sensible direction I should be able to arithmetic my way to the finish -- I just don't know what sort of questions to even ask to solve the problem on my own!